# Cannot resolve method 'forDefaultResourceLocation' in 'SpringFactoriesLoader'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)'

Cannot resolve method 'forDefaultResourceLocation' in 'SpringFactoriesLoader'

There is the basic code from SpringAppliacation:

```
private <T> List<T> getSpringFactoriesInstances(Class<T> type, ArgumentResolver argumentResolver) {
        return SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(getClassLoader()).load(type, argumentResolver);
}
```

And if it might help my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Spring3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Spring3Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I don't know that to do, because I can't change anything in this file. So that I can do?

I just start to learn Spring boot, use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: What versions of spring boot and spring are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when using IntelliJ Community version and run a project downloaded from Spring Initialiazr. The reason I had to download is because IntelliJ Community version does not provide Spring as Ultimate version does.

When I use the Ultimate IntelliJ (there is 30 days trial option) and create new project (same as yours), I can run it without any problem.

Initially I guess the issue comes from IntelliJ Community version, but then when I post question on Udemy, the assistant teacher said he can run it without any problem with Community version. So my choice is to use Ultimate version as it's not worth wasting time to find issue.

Hope this help!

Comment: I have an Ultimate version) But anyway I think I already solve problem in Feb. Unfortunately I didn't think to write the answer here and now I don't remember.